# How to replace Android adt bundle

Tags: android, windows, bundle, adt, reinstall

Please help me to solve the following problem: 
I have installed Android adt Bundle. Because it didn't work properly, I deleted the folder containing /eclipse/, /sdk/, and SDK Manager.exe and the folder .android from C:\Users\MyName and the problems remained for a new added adt-bundle. What have I to delete in order to add again adt-bundle on Windows 7 64 bit?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to check this : https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't related to any of that. If you can explain the problems encountered it would be better.

Comment: May be your ZIP file has a problem. Try to download ADT bundle again. There were some reports that the latest (June 2014) bundle was not good. You could try to install an earlier version. You can install it to any directory, but I don't recommend path with spaces (e.g. `c:\Program Files`). You don't have to install the new bundle "over" the old one, therefore there is no reason whatsoever to delete `eclipse` and `sdk` directories at the old location.

Comment: After I created a new project, in  res/values/strings.xml exists only app_name(String).
res/layout is empty and remained empty until the final.
After debug command the emulator displayed a white screen with the following text at the top: “Can’t connect to the Internet. Swipe for some tips”. The emulator didn’t answer at any command.
In console it was written:
HOME is up on device ‘emulator-5554’
Uploading SalutonMondo.apk auto device ‘emulator-5554’
Installing SalutonMondo.apk...
Failed to install SalutonMondo.apk on device ‘emulator-5554’!